# How to get substring from string using xpath 1.0 in lxml

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

This is the example HTML.

```
<html>
  <a href="HarryPotter:Chamber of Secrets">
    text
  </a>
  <a href="HarryPotter:Prisoners in Azkabahn">
    text
  </a>
</html>
```

I am in a situation where I need to extract

```
Chamber of Secrets
Prisoners in Azkabahn
```

I am using lxml 4.2.1 in python which uses xpathb1.0.
I have tried to extract using XPath

```
'substring-after(//a/@href,"HarryPotter:")'
```

which returns only `"Chamber of Secrets"`.

and with XPath

```
'//a/@href[substring-after(.,"HarryPotter:")]'
```

which returns

```
'HarryPotter:Chamber of Secrets'
'HarryPotter:Prisoners in Azkabahn'
```

I have researched for it and got new learning but didn't find the fix of my problem.

I have hit and tried different XPath using `substring-after`.

In my research, I got to know that it could also be accomplished by regex too, then I tried and failed.

I found that it is easy to manipulate a string in XPath 2.0 and above using regex but we can also use regex in XPath 1.0 using XSLT extensions.

Could we do it with `substring-after` function, if yes then what is the XPath and if No then what is the best approach to get the desired output?

And how we can get the desired output using regex in XPath by sticking to lxml.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach to get both text values:

```
from lxml import html

raw_source = """<html>
  <a href="HarryPotter:Chamber of Secrets">
    text
  </a>
  <a href="HarryPotter:Prisoners in Azkabahn">
    text
  </a>
</html>"""
source = html.fromstring(raw_source)

for link in source.xpath('//a'):
    print(link.xpath('substring-after(@href, "HarryPotter:")'))
```

Comment: So, I can play around with namespaces using `substring-after()` and `substring-before()` @sir Andersson!!

Comment: @SIM , do you mean to handle nodes, like `<ns:tag>...</ns:tag>`?

Comment: Yes, sir. That is what I meant.

Comment: @SIM , in this case `substring-after()` and `substring-before()` won't work. You might need to use `name()`/`local-name()` instead, e.g. `//*[name()="tag"]` to ignore namespaces

Comment: Your every single comment means a lot to me. Thanks sir for the clarity.

Comment: @Andersson but I need to achieve this using XPath without looping over the tag

Comment: @brainLoop , `lxml` doesn't support XPath like `//a/substring-after(@href, "HarryPotter:")`, so I'm not sure if you can get required output with XPath 1.0 syntax

Comment: @Andersson, ok, can I use regex instead substring-after in your answered code

Comment: @brainLoop Do you mean `re` library or `matches` XPath function? `matches` won't work also... You can try to split string as `[href.split("HarryPotter:")[-1] for href in source.xpath('//a/@href')]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `substring-after()` and `substring-before()` and together

Here is example:

from lxml import html

```
f_html = """<html><body><table><tbody><tr><td class="df9" width="20%">
         <a class="nodec1" href="javascript:reqDl(1254);" onmouseout="status='';" onmouseover="return dspSt();">
          <u>
           2014-2
          </u>
         </a>
        </td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>"""
tree_html = html.fromstring(f_html)
deal_id = tree_html.xpath("//td/a/@href")
print(tree_html.xpath('substring-after(//td/a/@href, "javascript:reqDl(")'))
print(tree_html.xpath('substring-before(//td/a/@href, ")")'))
print(tree_html.xpath('substring-after(substring-before(//td/a/@href, ")"), "javascript:reqDl(")'))
```

Result:

```
1254);
javascript:reqDl(1254
1254
```